# Convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} x^a e^{bx}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> For which values $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ does the integral
>
> $$
> \int_1^{+\infty} x^a e^{bx}\, dx
> $$
>   converge?

I bear in mind the case $\int_1^{+\infty} x e^{-x}\, dx$, that clearly converges. By similar arguments, if $a$ is a positive integer and $b<0$, we always have convergence by integral by parts.

> But what can I say in general? Does it suffice to take $b<0$ in order to ensure convergence?

Comment: in first place you need that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^ae^{bx}=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converges iff $b<0$ or ($b=0$ and $-a>1$)

Note that $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2} =1$$

- If $b<0$  then $x^{a+2}e^{bx} \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$

Hence for $x$ large enough  we have $$x^{a+2}e^{bx} <1\implies x^a e^{bx} \le\frac{1}{x^2} $$
the convergence  follows by comparison test.

- If $b=0$ and $a<-1$  that is  $-1-a>0$ then  we have $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{-a}} =[\frac{1}{(a+1)x^{-1-a}}]_1^\infty = -\frac{1}{(a+1)}$$
- Now if $b>0$ then then $x^{a+1}e^{bx} \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$

Hence for $x$ large enough  we have $$x^{a+1}e^{bx} >1\implies x^a e^{bx} >\frac{1}{x} $$
the divergence  follows by comparison test.

Comment: Can you prove it? (only the case $b<0$, if $b=0$ is clear).

Comment: Can someone please clarify why is this true?- "If $<0$ then $^{(+2)} ^{} \rightarrow 0 \quad as  \rightarrow \infty $"