# Convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a^x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ for $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I have to study the following improper integral:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{a^x}{\sqrt{x}}dx,\,\, a>0$$
I have thought that $a^x$ converges to 0 when $x\to \infty$ if $|a|<1$ so $\forall \epsilon\,\, \exists \,M>0: \forall x>M: |a^x|<\epsilon$.
So:
$$\frac{a^x}{\sqrt{x}}<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x}}:=g(x)$$
Now the integral of g(x) diverges but this does not help me to conclude the divergence of the initial integral.
How can I proceed?

Comment: This answers your question: [Convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} x^a e^{bx}\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633195/convergence-of-int-1-infty-xa-ebx-dx). (Apply it to  $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-1/2}e^{x\ln a}dx$.)

Comment: @AnneBauval ok thanks! Only a question...if the integrand function does not converge to 0 then can I conclude something yet?

Comment: If you mean in general, [the answer is no](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721590). But you can of course conclude if the integrand does have a limit which is $\ne0.$